# Inheritance With Kendo UI - Calling base method

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

Is it possible to call base method with Kendo javascript inheritance?
I try this:

```
function log(msg) {
    $("#content").append("<p>" + msg + "</p>");
}

var Person = kendo.Class.extend({
    firstName: 'Not Set',
    lastName: 'Not Set',
    isPrettyCoolPerson: false,
    init: function(firstName, lastName) {
        if (firstName) this.firstName = firstName;
        if (lastName) this.lastName = lastName;
    },
    sayHello: function() {
        log("Hello! I'm " + this.firstName + " " + this.lastName)
    }
});

var Parent = Person.extend({
    firstName: 'Mark',
    lastName: 'Holland',
    sayHello: function() {
        Person.sayHello.call(this);
        log("Hello from Parent! I'm " + this.firstName + " " + this.lastName)
    }
});

var myDad = new Parent();

myDad.sayHello();
```

and this:

```
function log(msg) {
    $("#content").append("<p>" + msg + "</p>");
}

var Person = kendo.Class.extend({
    firstName: 'Not Set',
    lastName: 'Not Set',
    isPrettyCoolPerson: false,
    init: function(firstName, lastName) {
        if (firstName) this.firstName = firstName;
        if (lastName) this.lastName = lastName;
    },
    sayHello: function() {
        log("Hello! I'm " + this.firstName + " " + this.lastName)
    }
});

var Parent = Person.extend({
    firstName: 'Mark',
    lastName: 'Holland',
    sayHello: function() {
        Person.call(this);
        log("Hello from Parent! I'm " + this.firstName + " " + this.lastName)
    }
});

var myDad = new Parent();

myDad.sayHello();
```

The only difference is Person.call(this); and Person.sayHello.call(this);.
But in either case it is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The methods get added to the prototype of the Person function, so you need to change this call:

```
Person.sayHello.call(this);
```

to

```
Person.prototype.sayHello.call(this);
```

or (equivalent)

```
Person.fn.sayHello.call(this);
```

Comment: Worth noting, if function has parameters then you just put the parameters right after `this`. Like `Person.fn.sayHello.call(this, first_name, last_name);`, if sayHello had two parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I like handling inheritance with Kendo UI using a single variable to store the base "class" and another to store the "class" being defined.  I declare both variables inside an immediately invoked inline function so they don't have scope outside the defining code.  Doing it like this makes it so if the base "class" changes, the code only has to change in 1 place:

```
var Person = (function () {
    var $base = kendo.Class;
    var $class = $base.extend({
        firstName: null,
        lastName: null,
        isPrettyCoolPerson: null,

        init: function (firstName, lastName) {
            if (firstName) this.firstName = firstName;
            if (lastName) this.lastName = lastName;
        },

        sayHello: function () {
            console.log("Hello! I'm " + this.firstName + " " + this.lastName);
        }
    });

    return $class;
})();

var Parent = (function () {
    var $base = Person;
    var $class = $base.extend({
        sayHello: function () {
            $base.fn.sayHello.call(this);

            console.log("...and I'm a parent!");
        }
    });

    return $class;
})();

var person = new Person("Steve", "Gates");
person.sayHello();

var parent = new Parent("Bill", "Jobs");
parent.sayHello();
```

You can also use this method when defining models:

```
var Shape = (function () {
    var $base = kendo.data.Model;
    var $class = $base.define({
        id: "Id",
        fields: {
            Id: { type: "number" },
            Name: { nullable: true },
            Area: { type: "number" }
        }
    });

    return $class;
})();

var Rectangle = (function () {
    var $base = Shape;
    var $class = $base.define({
        id: "Id",
        fields: {
            Width: { type: "number" },
            Height: { type: "number" }
        }
    });

    return $class;
})();

var shape = new Shape({ Id: 1, Name: "Amorphous Blob", Area: Math.E * Math.PI });
console.log(shape.Area);

var rectangle = new Rectangle({ Id: 2, Name: "Henry the Rectangle", Width: 3, Height: 4 });
rectangle.Area = rectangle.Width * rectangle.Height;
console.log(rectangle.Area);
```

Comment: This just means implementing inheritance on your own instead of actually using Kendo's inheritance implementation. Normally calling a parent method is a basic thing in classical inheritance. Thus any library claiming it implements classical inheritance has to implement it.

Besides, defining all these variable for each class means a lot of code repeating.

Comment: @German how does this answer satisfy the criteria for needing to be downvoted?  http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down

Comment: I thought it was reimplementing already implemented feature but I missed the point of not having to write the parent class name multiple times. I should have read it more attentively. I am sorry.